# How to use JSTL variable as the name of a HTML link

Tags: html, jstl

My JSTL variable is not being interpreted between the `<a> </a>` tags. As a result, no link are being displayed on my page.
${page} is also not being interpreted in the `<c:param>` tag. Any idea? in that case, the link that results is /listing.htm?page= instead of something like /list.htm?page=2 for example.

```
<li>
  <a href="<c:url value="/list.htm" >
    <c:param name="page" value="${page}"/></c:url>">
  ${page}
  </a>
</li>
```

I have also tried this way but it does not make any difference:

```
<li>
  <a href="<c:url value="/listing.htm" >
    <c:param name="page" value="${page}"/></c:url>">
  <c:out value="${page}"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the problem was not coming from this code. Inside the foreach, I gave a different variable name to my variable so of course it was inaccessible.

I was having the following code:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>        
        <c:forEach begin="${startpage}" end="${endpage}" var="p">
            <li><a href="<c:url value="/list.htm" >
                               <c:param name="page" value="${page}"/>
                             </c:url>"><c:out value="${page}"></c:out>
                </a>
            </li>                       
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
<div>
```